# Why is clang/llvm throwing me this error using Bazel while building carbon

Tags: clang, llvm, carbon-lang

So I am trying to build [carbon-lang](https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang#getting-started) i have done everything, installed clang/llvm it works fine but when I run the command `bazel run //explorer -- ./explorer/testdata/print/format_only.carbon`
it gives me this error I have googled but cannot find the solution to this error:

```
[bret@archxbret carbon-lang]$ bazel run //explorer -- ./explorer/testdata/print/format_only.carbon 
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it... 
INFO: Invocation ID: 6fb0bb2c-cc78-4fb0-8e35-90759b75109d 
INFO: Analyzed target //explorer:explorer (67 packages loaded, 1567 targets configured). 
INFO: Found 1 target... 
ERROR: /home/bret/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bret/e6835bf0f6859c4bbbb42f026d02cce5/external/m4_v1.4.18/bin/BUILD. bazel:2:10: Linking external/m4_v1.4.18/bin/m4 (for host] failed: (Exit 1): 
clang++ failed: error executing command /us r/bin/clang++ Obazel-out/host/bin/external/m4_v1.4.18/bin/m4-2.params

Jse --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging 
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc++ 
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -l:libunwind.a  
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -l:libunwind.a
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Target //explorer:explorer failed to build
Jse --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps. 
INFO: Elapsed time: 29.584s, Critical Path: 0.68s 
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal. 
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully 
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I am using arch Linux any help is appreciated I have tried adding llvm to path but it doesn't seem to work.
the llvm is in /usr/include/llvm but when I add it to my .bashrc and source it it shows up in when I `echo $PATH` but when I run the command `which llvm` it shows that no llvm found in the current added to PATH directories unlike when I run `which clang` it shows that it is found in `/usr/bin`
but the command `llvm-config --version` works so I am not sure if it means that is already added to PATH or not.
I am really lost here any help is appreciated.
apologies in advance if I made an obvious mistake.

Comment: I found the solution to the:`ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc++ ` by installing `libc++` but the other two still persist.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pacman -S libunwind`?

Comment: Yes I did but it was already installed but for the sake of it I reinstalled it. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after Rigorously searching for a solution to this error it turns out that carbon has issues with system installed versions of `clang` and `llvm` and for now if you want the carbon-lang to work you have to install `llvm` with `homebrew`.

Comment: I also tried using system-installed packages for an hour. After giving up and trying `brew`, everything worked fine.